# Al bajar un archivo frmservlet.jnlp, chrome lo baja sin extensión

Tags: chrome, extensiones

Buen día. Estamos configurando un cliente para usar Oracle EBS, por lo cual, para abrir forms, se descarga un servlet, el archivo jnlp que abre la aplicación de ventanas de Oracle.

En este cliente en particular, que cuenta con la ultima version de Chrome (119.0.6045.106 build oficial 64-bits) y Windows 10, al dar click en la aplicación, se descarga el archivo, pero no se puede abrir ya que, no tiene extensión, solo el nombre. Entonces hay que agregarle manualmente la extensión para que abra.

Sin embargo, en otros equipos con la misma configuración aparentemente, esto no ocurre, el archivo baja normal a la carpeta de descargas y se ejecuta sin hacer nada mas. ¿Hay algo que haya pasado por alto?